# nodejs pass server instance to a class as a property

Tags: node.js

I have a question about passing an instance, as following

app.js

```
// nodejs var
var app = express()
    , server = http.createServer(app)
    , _Server = io.listen(server);


/**
 * To log
 * Before, to display the _Server instance, the content should be
 */
console.log(util.inspect(_Server));


// app var
var _Session = new Session(_Server);
```

session.js

```
var Session = function Session(server) {
    this.m_server = server;

    /**
     * To log
     * After, to display the m_server property, the content actually is
     */
    console.log(util.inspect(this.m_server));
}
```

I wonder why those results aren't the same as I expect. And as a result I couldn't call 
this.m_server.emit(...) in the Session class.
What I want to do is to delegate a behavior

```
from
    _Server.emit(...) // in app.js
to
    this.m_server.emit(...) // in session.js
```

So that lots of events could be implemented in different files.
How can I do to make it ? thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

app.js:

```
_Server = module.exports.io = io.listen(server);
```

session.js:

```
this.m_server = require('app').io;
```

Comment: it works but actually it's kind of GLOBAL way instead of a parameter. As I know, global is evil. So is there other way to do ?
I still appreciate your answer.